# specific id is not passing to ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is a part of my code, and when user clicks the button it retrieve the data from database regarding to id (ie i am not geting net_id) i am also getting an error

```
TypeError: $(...).attr(...) is undefined


arr = $(this).attr('class').split( " " );
```

HTML

```
<td class="edit2 '.$rows["net_id"].' "> <input type="button" id="edit2" value="R" /> </td>
```

Ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#edit2").click(function() {       

         arr = $(this).attr('class').split( " " );

         var clientid=document.getElementById("client").value;         

      $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
        type: "POST",
        url: "clientnetworkpricelist/display.php",    
        data: "clientid="+ clientid+"&rowid="+arr[1],       

        success: function(response){                    
            $("#responsecontainer").html(response); 
            //alert(response);
        }

    });
});
});

</script>
```

Display.php

```
<?php
$dbHost = 'localhost'; // usually localhost
$dbUsername = 'xxxxxxx';
$dbPassword = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
$dbDatabase = 'fms';
$db = mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword) or die ("Unable to connect to Database Server.");
mysql_select_db ($dbDatabase, $db) or die ("Could not select database.");

$client_id=$_POST['clientid'];

        $rownum=$_POST['rowid'];  
        $sql="select status from $client_id WHERE net_id = ".$rownum."";

         print $sql;

        mysql_query($sql);  

?>
```

Comment: For one thing, this `net_id = ".$rownum.""` should be `net_id = '" . $rownum . "'`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Not necessarily, say if `$rownum` is integer, the code given/being used is correct then.

Comment: ok bu it showing error as TypeError: $(...).attr(...) is undefined
 

arr = $(this).attr('class').split( " " );

Comment: Really? I seen this so often, I don't know when it's right or wrong anymore. lol @hjpotter92 thanks

Comment: Look into using `data-` attributes instead of storing data in the class.

Comment: Fix your quotes errors: `<td class="edit2 '.$rows["net_id"].' ">` must be `<td class="edit2 ".$rows["net_id"]." ">` and may be missing `<?php` tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to get the class of $(this), which is the button you have clicked on. But that button has no classes. It is the parent of the button you click on you want the classes from.

Change this line:

```
arr = $(this).attr('class').split( " " );
```

to this:

```
arr = $(this).parent().attr('class').split( " " );
```

Comment: thanks you , it worked but i am having same button repeating for more than 10 row it works with the first row button .if i click the second row button its nor performing the function(ie nothing will happen)

Comment: @arokia - That's because you bind the click event to the button using an ID, #edit2, ID's are supposed to be unique on a page. Try using a class on your button, something like class="edit_button", then instead of $("#edit2").click, use $(".edit_button").click

Answer (score 0):

You have change below line:

```
arr = $(this).attr('class').split( " " );
```

to

```
arr = $(this).parent().attr('class').split( " " );
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the following line:

```
arr = $(this).attr('class').split( " " );
```

You are trying to get the class attribute of the **button** that is clicked and thus it isn't able to find the class that you need. Instead what you have to do is get to the parent of the button i.e. `td` and get the class attribute from it. Here is how:

```
arr = $(this).parent().attr('class').split( " " );
```